# while sentinel variable with post-increment operator

Tags: c, pointers, post-increment

what's the difference between:

```
while(*s++ != '\0') {}
```

and

```
while(*s != '\0') {
   s++;
}
```

`s` is a `char *`. The latter works OK. but at the end of first loop, `*s` is not equal to `'\0'`.

Comment: In the first statement, `s` will wind up pointing one char past the null char when the while loop exits.  In the second example, `s` will wind up pointing to the null char when the while loop exits.

Comment: The loop control will be the same, it's just a matter of where `s` points after the loop completes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of

```
 while(*s++ != '\0') {}
```

the increment is done as a post increment operator, in the condition-check statement itself. In this case, the value change (increment) is the side effect after the value computation for the operator. Thus, after the value is used (in comparison), `s` gets incremented.

On the other hand,

```
while(*s != '\0') {
   s++;
}
```

the increment takes place as post-increment inside the conditional block, which will only execute if the condition is TRUTHY. Once the condition is evaluated to be false, `s` is not incremented.